# how to execute unix command in php

Tags: php, unix

i am trying to execute unix command in php script like this.

```
<?php

echo shell_exec('head -n 1 log_list_23072014|awk  -F ',' '{print $2}'');

?>
```

This is the file , trying to get the first column of the first row.

```
NODE,CGR,TERMID,VMGW,ET
```

but the error message i am getting

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'shell_exec' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'.
```

cant able to find please help.

Comment: `shell_exec()` expects **1** parameter, you're parsing **2**.

Comment: epects 1 parameter means, i dint get and the parameters which i passed is correct or wrong or else please share the code to get 1st column of the 1st row

Comment: You're doing this: `shell_exec(FIRSTITEM , SECOND ITEM);` and the function **can only** do this `shell_exec(FIRSTITEM);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you've used is not valid, you have to escape single quotes inside your string:

```
<?php echo shell_exec('head -n 1 log_list_23072014|awk  -F \',\' \'{print $2}\'');
```

You can also use `exec()`

Comment: Slight tweak: you need not quote the comma, and then you need not escape those quotes. In addition, `awk` can do the equivalent of `head -n1` by itself: `' awk -F, \'NR==1{print $2;exit}\' '`

Answer (score 1):

There was an extra `'` within your command. Using your command in a variable can help with identifying errors, and when using the standard `exec` it's required.

```
$cmd = 'head -n 1 log_list_23072014 | awk -F , \'{print $2}\'';
echo shell_exec($cmd);
```

changing it to the format above should work.

Comment: Wrong. [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php). Only one `$cmd` can be passed. EDIT: +1 better for referencing `exec`